# Vue Display Nested Objects as td (Rows)

Tags: html, vue.js, nested

I want to display the data as a row. Dynamic in case the api has several rows, but i'm only able to show it horizontal due to the nesting I have for the objects. Nesting is tricky for me. Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
<tr class="text-left border-b-2 border-gray-300">
    <th class="px-4 py-3">Name</th>
    <th class="px-4 py-3">Visibility</th>
    <th class="px-4 py-3">Project</th>
    <th class="px-4 py-3">Branch</th>
    <th class="px-4 py-3">State</th>
    <th class="px-4 py-3">Failed Runs</th>
    <th class="px-4 py-3">Total Runs</th>
    <th class="px-4 py-3">Success Percentage</th>
  </tr>
  

 <tr class="bg-gray-100 border-b border-gray-200" >
      
     
      <div v-for="currentView in getDashboard()" :key="currentView.id">
       {{ currentView.name }}  {{ currentView.visibility }} 

        <div>
          <div v-for="subTask in currentView.projects" :key="subTask.id">
           {{ subTask.name }} 
            <div>
              <div v-for="subTask2 in subTask.branchs" :key="subTask2.id">
                 {{ subTask2.name }}  {{ subTask2.state }} 
                <div>
                  <div v-for="subTask3 in subTask2" :key="subTask3.id">
                    {{ subTask3.branchName }} {{ subTask3.projectName }}  {{ subTask3.organizationName }} {{ subTask3.failedRuns }} {{ subTask3.failedRuns }}  {{ subTask3.successRunsPercentage }} 
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       </tr>
```

Edit:
The structure of the data i'm capturing looks like this. Object that includes array of objects.

```
[
    {
        "id": "sss",
        "name": "TestDemo",
        "visibility": "ss",
        "projects": [
            {
                "name": "ss",
                "branchs": [
                    {
                        "name": "master",
                        "state": "none",
                        "report": {
                            "branchName": "master",
                            "projectName": "ss",
                            "organizationName": "TestDemo",
                            "failedRuns": 0,
                            "totalRuns": 0,
                            "successRunsPercentage": 100
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What does the data look like?  Table rows (`tr`) should have table data cells (`td`) as children.

Comment: Yes, but they also have to be nested as I have nested objects and array. As shown in the code. I want to display each binded data inside td. To have a logical row, you know...

Comment: I would create a computed property that flattens the data out then.

Comment: Good idea. Can you pass me a starting point though? An example or something as I am not sure what i'm looking for.

Comment: If you edit and add an example of what your data looks like I could

Comment: Done. Really appreciated!